# npm installs @types/.../node_modules/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am using react (tsx), react-table, react-i18next with @types.

When I run an npm i, @types/react-table and @types/react-i18next also installs react typings in its folder as a subfolder. So I end up with multiple copies of @types/react in each related @types module. As a result typescript throws an error when trying to run the app, and when I delete the node_modules in @types\react-table, @types\react-i18next folder, it compiles fine.

I am using npm 6.5.0 and node 8.15.
This behaviour is different on my colleague's computers (all of them are running on Mac OS Mojave), it does not install nested @types\react on above listed packages.

**EDIT**:
Moved @types to devDependencies, looks like this resolved it.

Comment: Try to install the second one without optional dependencies whit the following additional parameter 
 `--no-optional`

Comment: @Atomzwieback this parameter (--no-optional) is not saved in package json, so when we do npm install, it still tries to install @types\react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem there is no final solution yet because it's not possible atm to safe the `--no-optional` parameter so there is already a closed feature request at the npm GitHub repo which you can found here:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14185

So there is atm only the option to exclude the package and every new dev have to install it themselves with the `--no-optional` param otherwise you have the option to add it to the dev dependency’s via the `--save-dev` option which resolves the problem but it is a kind of dirty solution even it seems like this is the only solution for it because the npm devs will not add the feature in the near future.